# Convolutional neural network back propagation - delta calculation in convolutional layer

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution, backpropagation

So I’m trying to make a CNN and so far I think I understand all of the forward propagation and the back propagation in the fully connected layers. However, I’m having some issues with the back prop in the convolutional layers.

Basically I’ve written out the dimensions of everything at each stage in a CNN with two convolutional layers and two fully connected layers, with the input having a depth of 1(as it is black and white) and only one filter being applied at each convolutional layer. I haven’t bothered to use pooling at this stage as to my knowledge it shouldn’t have any impact on the calculus, just to where it is assigned, so the dimensions should still fit as long as I also don’t include any uppooling in my backprop. I also haven’t bothered to write out the dimensions after the application of the activation functions as they would be the same as that as their input and I would be writing the same values twice.

The dimensions, as you will see, vary slightly in format. For the convolutional layers I’ve written them as though they are images, rather than in a matrix form. Whilst for the fully connected layers I’ve written the dimensions as that of the size of the matrices used(will hopefully make more sense when you see it).

The issue is that in calculating the delta for the convolutional layers, the dimensions don’t fit, what am I doing wrong?

Websites used:

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/
http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#the_cross-entropy_cost_function
http://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/

Calculation of dimensions:

[image: Image of workings]